# Always using project CRS when adding new layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, layers

I'm using QGIS 3 to load multiple layers, however if I have set a CRS(say, a UTM) for a blank project and then add a new layer, the project CRS changes to the CRS of that layer (say, WGS 1984) instead of keeping as UTM. I need to keep all layers I add for this project to be reprojected on-the-fly as UTM. Is it ever possible?

This is not a duplicate question. I need QGIS behave like follows: Every time I create a new project using a CRS I designated, say EPSG:3395, I can change default CRS in QGIS options to EPSG:3395 like what is suggested in that question, and all newly added layer will be reprojected to EPSG:3395; However, if I create a new project and change its CRS before adding any layer, say, WGS 1984, I need to change **two** CRS settings separately in Project settings and QGIS options, which seems quite unnatural to me. I'd like default CRS for newly added layers be controlled project-wise instead of application-wise.

Comment: Change configuration as stated in answer from above link to avoid the default unwanted behaviour

Comment: I edited my question and I don't think that question is a duplicate. @ThomasG77

Comment: There is a setting in the Options | CRS which - under 'CRS for New Layers' - you can select 'Use Project CRS' which will enable any new layers to adopt the Project CRS.

Comment: @nr_aus That option is useless when I add any existing layer from SHP file or spatial DB.

Comment: I see the problem: in the options, for project CRS you have only two possible settings: set the project CRS to the CRS of the first layer you load or use a fixed, pre-defined CRS. Both is not what you want. You want to open QGIS, set a project CRS (not the one defined as default in the options) and want every layer loaded to reproject on the fly to this project CRS. Maybe it's case for a feature request?

Comment: Well, it seems that it's really a feature missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I have misunderstood the intention of the QGIS developers, or just because their description in the GUI is misleading...
If I choose to "use the CRS of the first layer", it behaves as it says; However, if I change the option to "use default CRS" to the CRS I desired before creating a project, I will no longer need to change the project CRS again. That is said, I just need to change the CRS in QGIS Options once rather than setting it twice in both Project Properties and QGIS Options.